# Plot a hyperbolic plane tessellation

Tags: code-golf, graphical-output

Make a plot (Poincare disk) of a tessellation on a hyperbolic plane, such as:

[image]

The program takes *four* inputs:

1) How many edges/polygon (three in this example).

2) How many intersect at each vertex (seven in this example).

3) How many steps away from the center vertex to render (5 in this example, if you look closely). This means that a vertex is included iff it can be reached in 5 or less steps form the center. Edges are rendered iff both their vertexes are included.

4) The resolution of the image (a single number of pixels, the image is square).

The output must be an image. Edges must be rendered as circle-arcs, not lines (the Poincaré disk projection turns lines into circles). Points do not need to be rendered. When the user puts in something that is *not* hyperbolic (i.e. 5 triangles meeting at each vertex), the program does not have to work properly. This is code-golf, so the shortest answer wins.

Comment: Made more clear.

Comment: Much clearer now :)

Comment: It's implicit, but it might be better to make it explicit that a) the Poincaré disk model should be used (unless you're also open to half-plane model answers); b) a vertex should be rendered in the centre of the disk, and not the centre of a polygon.

Comment: Must a vertex lie at the centre of the disk?  Or can the centre of the disk be the centre of a polygon?

Comment: This really needs more background info. I've looked at a couple of sites (there are none mentioned in the question) and I cannot figure out the exact specification for drawing the example figure, let alone the general case. If it isn't specifed you may get invalid answers that people have worked hard on (for example I understand the non-radial lines are represented as arcs of circles, but someone might take a shortcut and do straight lines.) Also, it seems the edgelength of the lines from the centre vertex (as a percentage of circle radius) needs to be specified.

Comment: Are number of edges in each vertex and the number of edges of each face independent?

Comment: steverrill: the Poincaré disk is a specific definition, but I made sure to specify that edges must be circles. flawr: Yes, but certain combinations are not hyperbolic.

Comment: I see you've specified that the edges have to be arcs now, but you haven't addressed my other points: There's still not enough information in the question to define a what is valid output (and nor is there any indication of where to find it). Voting to close (I see I'm not the first). It's a pity because I like the idea of the question.

Comment: Here's a pretty cool [**demonstration**](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/TilingTheHyperbolicPlaneWithRegularPolygons/) if you want to look.

Comment: From the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_tilings_in_hyperbolic_plane) on uniform tilings in the hyperbolic plane, it appears that the "standard" way of showing these tilings is with a polygon in the center. Like in the Mathematica answer given already. Could you update the question to ask for this?

Comment: Maybe it is more standard, but it is a bit late to update the question, and its good that the "stock" examples need to be modified.

Comment: What if the number of pixels isn't a square number?

Comment: @LevelRiverSt regarding "Also, it seems the edgelength of the lines from the centre vertex (as a percentage of circle radius) needs to be specified." - no, there's only one  length that works for a given p,q: it's sqrt(1 - sin^2(pi/q)/cos^2(pi/p)).

Answer (score 3):

## Mathematica, 2535 bytes

Taken from [**here**](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/65215/how-to-create-a-poincare-disk-type-kaleidoscope-in-mathematica) (hence why it's community wiki). Not really that golfed. View the provided link for the author's explanation of his code.

Also, I'm no Mathematica expert, but I bet Martin could do wonders on the code length. I don't even understand the math behind it.

I left it readable, but if the question doesn't get closed, I'll golf it past readability and move the 2 other parameters inside the caller function.

**Currently invalid**, feel free to help improve it:

- I think this uses lines rather than arcs.
- Centered on a face, rather than a vertex.

```mathematica
HyperbolicLine[{{Px_, Py_}, {Qx_, Qy_}}] := 
 If[N[Chop[Px Qy - Py Qx]] =!= 0., 
  Circle[OrthoCentre[{{Px, Py}, {Qx, Qy}}], 
   OrthoRadius[{{Px, Py}, {Qx, Qy}}], 
   OrthoAngles[{{Px, Py}, {Qx, Qy}}]], Line[{{Px, Py}, {Qx, Qy}}]]

OrthoCentre[{{Px_, Py_}, {Qx_, Qy_}}] := 
 With[{d = 2 Px Qy - 2 Py Qx, p = 1 + Px^2, q = 1 + Qx^2 + Qy^2}, 
  If[N[d] =!= 0., {p Qy + Py^2 Qy - Py q, -p Qx - Py^2 Qx + Px q}/d, 
   ComplexInfinity]]

OrthoRadius[{{Px_, Py_}, {Qx_, Qy_}}] := 
 If[N[Chop[Px Qy - Py Qx]] =!= 0., 
  Sqrt[Total[OrthoCentre[{{Px, Py}, {Qx, Qy}}]^2] - 1], Infinity]

OrthoAngles[{{Px_, Py_}, {Qx_, Qy_}}] := 
 Block[{a, b, c = OrthoCentre[{{Px, Py}, {Qx, Qy}}]}, 
  If[(a = N[Apply[ArcTan, {Px, Py} - c]]) < 0., a = a + 2 \[Pi]];
  If[(b = N[Apply[ArcTan, {Qx, Qy} - c]]) < 0., 
   b = b + 2 \[Pi]]; {a, b} = Sort[{a, b}];
  If[b - a > \[Pi], {b, a + 2 \[Pi]}, {a, b}]]

Inversion[Circle[{Cx_, Cy_}, r_], {Px_, Py_}] := {Cx, Cy} + 
  r^2 {Px - Cx, Py - Cy}/((Cx - Px)^2 + (Cy - Py)^2)
Inversion[Circle[{Cx_, Cy_}, r_, {a_, b_}], {Px_, Py_}] := {Cx, Cy} + 
  r^2 {Px - Cx, Py - Cy}/((Cx - Px)^2 + (Cy - Py)^2)

Inversion[Circle[{Cx_, Cy_}, r_, {a_, b_}], p_Line] := 
 Map[Inversion[Circle[{Cx, Cy}, r], #] &, p, {2}]

Inversion[Circle[{Cx_, Cy_}, r_, {a_, b_}], p_Polygon] := 
 Map[Inversion[Circle[{Cx, Cy}, r], #] &, p, {2}]

Inversion[Line[{{Px_, Py_}, {Qx_, Qy_}}], {Ux_, Uy_}] := 
 With[{u = Px - Qx, 
   v = Qy - Py}, {-Ux (v^2 - u^2) - 2 u v Uy, 
    Uy (v^2 - u^2) - 2 u v Ux}/(u^2 + v^2)]
Inversion[Line[{{Px_, Py_}, {Qx_, Qy_}}], p_Polygon] := 
 Map[Inversion[Line[{{Px, Py}, {Qx, Qy}}], #] &, p, {2}]

Inversion[Circle[{Cx_, Cy_}, r_], c_List] := 
 Map[Inversion[Circle[{Cx, Cy}, r], #] &, c]


PolygonInvert[p_Polygon] := 
 Map[Inversion[HyperbolicLine[#], p] &, 
  Partition[Join[p[[1]], {p[[1, 1]]}], 2, 1]]
PolygonInvert[p_List] := Flatten[Map[PolygonInvert[#] &, p]]

LineRule = Polygon[x_] :> Line[Join[x, {x[[1]]}]];
HyperbolicLineRule = 
  Polygon[x_] :> 
   Map[HyperbolicLine, Partition[Join[x, {x[[1]]}], 2, 1]];

CentralPolygon[p_Integer, q_Integer, \[Phi]_: 0] := 
 With[{r = (Cot[\[Pi]/p] Cot[\[Pi]/q] - 1)/
     Sqrt[Cot[\[Pi]/p]^2 Cot[\[Pi]/q]^2 - 1], \[Theta] = \[Pi] Range[
       1, 2 p - 1, 2]/p}, 
  r Map[{{Cos[\[Phi]], -Sin[\[Phi]]}, {Sin[\[Phi]], Cos[\[Phi]]}}.# &,
     Transpose[{Cos[\[Theta]], Sin[\[Theta]]}]]]

PolygonUnion[p_Polygon, tol_: 10.^-10] := p
PolygonUnion[p_List, tol_: 10.^-10] := 
 With[{q = p /. Polygon[x_] :> N[Polygon[Round[x, 10.^-10]]]}, 
  DeleteDuplicates[q]]
HyperbolicTessellation[p_Integer, q_Integer, \[Phi]_, k_Integer, 
  t_: 10.^-10] := 
 Map[PolygonUnion[#, t] &, 
   NestList[PolygonInvert, Polygon[CentralPolygon[p, q, \[Phi]]], 
     k][[{-2, -1}]]] /; k > 0

HyperbolicTessellation[p_Integer, q_Integer, \[Phi]_, k_Integer, 
  t_: 10.^-10] := Polygon[CentralPolygon[p, q, \[Phi]]] /; k == 0
HyperbolicTessellationGraphics[p_Integer, q_Integer, \[Phi]_, 
  k_Integer, rule_RuleDelayed, opts___] := 
 Graphics[{Circle[{0, 0}, 1], 
   HyperbolicTessellation[p, q, \[Phi], k, 10.^-10] /. rule}, opts]
```

Called like:

```mathematica
HyperbolicTessellationGraphics[7, 3, 0., 5, HyperbolicLineRule, ImageSize -> 100, PlotLabel -> "{7,3}"]
HyperbolicTessellationGraphics[3, 7, 0., 7, HyperbolicLineRule, ImageSize -> 300, PlotLabel -> "{7,7}"]
```

[image: 7,3 tiling] [image: 3,7 tiling]

Comment: This looks like the ultimate wall of text. +1

Comment: @kirbyfan64sos Yeah, deciphering this is a beast. I'm pretty sure there's only a few changes necessary to make it arcs instead of hyperbolic lines. Also, changing the functions/parameters to single-char names would reduce the size by a lot.

Comment: This is invalid, as it is centred on a face, not a vertex. But the original link does at least give some kind of definition of what is to be done here.

Comment: I was wondering if it was lines or arcs. It's hard to tell at this low resolution, but they actually might be arcs, just not very... arcy. For example, it looks like the line on the right side of the central polygon is slightly bent to the inside.

Comment: @RetoKoradi It's entirely possible, and may be a side-effect of having the image centered on the face, rather than a vertex. Idk. Check out the `LineRule` and `HyperbolicLineRule` for the relevant lines.

Comment: I cannot get your code to run on Mathematica 10.2.  By the way, if you reduce the number of  sides on the polygon, you should see arcs.

Comment: The original code works.  Yours appears to have suffered when you cut and pasted. (It's unlikely that it was mine since I only had to cut and paste once.)

Comment: I have another approach, based on another person's code, that I've been able to pare down to 1100 bytes.   But, once golfed, the code becomes indecipherable. I believe the same would happen if we golf your submission.  At the moment, I am trying to understand how they work in verbose format.

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript/HTML/SVG, 5086 bytes

Not golfed, but the logic/math is short and hopefully relatively clear; also does the planar and spherical tessellations ((p-2)*(q-2) <= 4) without too much extra logic (it was easier to implement those than to leave gaps in the table!).

The calling code in the snippet below calls the function several times: first to display the 512x512 {3,7} picture (not shown here; it looks just like the above), and then to display a 128x128 {p,q} (meaning q p-gons surround each vertex) for each p,q from 3 to 9:
[image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <!--
 https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/55848/plot-a-hyperbolic-plane-tessellation
 -->
 <style> svg { border: 1px solid black; } </style>
 <body>
  <script>
   "use strict";
   console.log("    in script");
   // Do an immediately invoked async function,
   // so we can sleep in it (to flush drawing).
   (async () => {
 console.log("        in script async function");
 const t0 = performance.now();

 // ==========================
 // IMPLEMENTATION BEGINS HERE

 // some complex math
 const neg = ([x,y]) => [-x,-y];
 const conj = ([x,y]) => [x,-y];
 const plus = (a,b) => [a[0]+b[0],a[1]+b[1]];
 const minus = (a,b) => [a[0]-b[0],a[1]-b[1]];
 const cross = (a,b) => a[0]*b[1]-a[1]*b[0];  // area of spanned parallelogram
 const times = (a,b) => [a[0]*b[0]-a[1]*b[1], a[0]*b[1]+a[1]*b[0]];
 const timesreal = ([x,y],r) => [x*r, y*r];
 const abs2 = ([x,y]) => x**2+y**2;
 const abs = z => Math.sqrt(abs2(z));
 const dist = (a,b) => abs(minus(a,b));
 const inverse = z => timesreal(conj(z), 1/abs2(z));
 const dividedby = (a,b) => times(a,inverse(b));

 // Transform z by the translation that takes the origin to t.
 // Works with any curvature; in particular:
 //   -1 = hyperbolic (poincare disk)
 //    0 = planar,
 //    1 = spherical (stereographic projection)
 const Plus = (z,t, curvature) => {
   // (z + t) / (1 - curvature*conj(t)*z)
   return dividedby(plus(z,t),
                    minus([1,0],
                          timesreal(times(conj(t), z), curvature)));
 };
 // Transform z by the translation that takes t to the origin.
 const Minus = (z,t, curvature) => Plus(z, neg(t), curvature);

 // Simple monotonic function of actual distance. Specifically:
 // - hyperbolic distance is 2*atanh(chord distance)
 // - spherical distance is 2*atan(chord distance)
 // - planar distance is chord distance
 // (I might be off by a factor of 2 in some of these claims, doesn't matter)
 const ChordDistance = (a,b, curvature) => abs(Minus(a,b, curvature));

 // signed radius of the circle passing through a,b,c
 const circumradius = (a,b,c) => dist(a,b)*dist(b,c)*dist(c,a) /
                                 (2 * cross(minus(b,a), minus(c,a)));

 // signed radius of circle needed to render segment a,b as circular arc
 // in the picture; may be infinite
 const ArcRadius = (a,b, curvature) => {
   if (curvature === 0) return Infinity;  // planar picture: all straight lines
   if (abs(a) > 1e3 || abs(b) > 1e3) return Infinity;  // one of them is infinite
   if (Math.abs(cross(a,b)) < 1e-3) return Infinity;  // collinear with origin
   // Let c be any third point on the arc
   const c = Plus(timesreal(Minus(b,a, curvature), .5), a, curvature);
   return circumradius(a,b,c);
 };


 const doit = (svgsize,p,q,steps,maxverts) => {
  const curvature = Math.sign(4-(p-2)*(q-2));  // -1:hyperbolic, 0:planar, 1:spherical
  const Dist = (a,b) => ChordDistance(a,b, curvature);

  const euclidean_first_edge_length = curvature===0 ? 1 :
    Math.sqrt(Math.abs((Math.sin(Math.PI/q)/Math.cos(Math.PI/p))**2 - 1))

  // a,b are generators of the symmetry group (not including reflections):
  //  - a is rotation by 2pi/q about origin
  //  - b is rotation by pi about first edge midpoint
  const primitive_qth_root_of_unity = [Math.cos(2*Math.PI/q),
                                       Math.sin(2*Math.PI/q)];
  const a = z => times(z, primitive_qth_root_of_unity);
  const b = ([x,y]) => Plus([-x, -y], [0,-euclidean_first_edge_length], curvature);

  // generate verts
  const vs = [[0,0]];
  for (let i = 0; i < steps; ++i) {
    for (const g of [b,a]) {
      for (let j = 0; j < vs.length; ++j) {  // while vs is growing
        if (vs.length >= maxverts) break;
        const v = g(vs[j]);
        if (vs.findIndex(w=>Dist(v,w)<=1e-6)<0) vs.push(v);
      }
    }
  }

  // generate edges (pairs of points, not pairs of indices)
  const es = [];
  if (vs.length >= 2) {
    const d = Dist(vs[0], vs[1]);
    for (let i = 0; i < vs.length; ++i) {
      for (let j = 0; j < i; ++j) {
        if (Math.abs(Dist(vs[i],vs[j]) - d) <= 1e-6) es.push([vs[i], vs[j]]);
      }
    }
  }

  const scale =
      curvature>0 ? .35 :  // spherical: get all verts in the picture
      curvature===0 ? 1/5.5 :  // planar: get a good sampling in the picture
      1;  // hyperbolic: get the poincare disk in the picture

  let svg_html = '<svg width="'+svgsize+'" height="'+svgsize+'"><path d="';
  for (let [a,b] of es) {
    const r = ArcRadius(a,b,curvature)*scale/2*svgsize;

    // if a or b is at infinity, then draw straight outward
    // from the other point
    if (abs(a) > 1e2) a = timesreal(b, 1e2);
    if (abs(b) > 1e2) b = timesreal(a, 1e2);

    const x0 = (a[0]*scale+1)/2*svgsize;
    const y0 = (a[1]*scale+1)/2*svgsize;
    const x1 = (b[0]*scale+1)/2*svgsize;
    const y1 = (b[1]*scale+1)/2*svgsize;

    if (!Number.isFinite(r)) {
      svg_html += 'M'+x0+','+y0+'L'+x1+','+y1;  // straight line
    } else {
      // circular arc of signed radius r
      svg_html += 'M'+x0+','+y0+'A'+r+','+r+',0,0,'+(r<0?1:0)+','+x1+','+y1;
    }
  }
  svg_html += '" stroke="black" fill="none"/></svg>';
  return svg_html;
 }; // doit

 // IMPLEMENTATION ENDS HERE
 // ========================


 document.body.innerHTML += doit(512, 3, 7, 5, 1000)
 document.body.innerHTML += "<br>";

 const sleep = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

 const svgsize = 128;
 const max = 9;
 const steps = 5;
 const maxverts = 1000;  // keep from going off the rails
 for (let p = 3; p <= max; ++p) {
   for (let q = 3; q <= max; ++q) {
     await sleep(0);  // flush previously drawn stuff before computing next
     document.body.innerHTML += doit(svgsize, p, q, steps, maxverts);
   }
   document.body.innerHTML += "<br>";
 }

 const t1 = performance.now();
 console.log("        out script async function in "+(t1-t0)/1000+"s")
   })();
   console.log("    out script")
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```